# Do serotonergic (5-HT2A-mediated) psychedelics elicit stimulant effects?

Tags: pharmacology, neurotransmitter, receptor, serotonin, hallucinogens

I know that 5-HT<sub>2A</sub> partial agonism is the key mechanism of action of serotonergic psychedelics but I also know that some research (e.g. the selective (no activity on any other known receptor sites) 5-HT<sub>2A</sub> inverse agonist/antagonist eplivanserin was being investigated as a sedative) says that central blockade of the 5-HT<sub>2A</sub> receptors induces sedation which is in opposition to the effect of 5-HT<sub>2A</sub> partial agonists.

I have a partial answer to my question. I heard from LSD users that they find it regularly **causes sleeplessness for the duration of its effects**, which is likely due to stimulant/wakefulness-promoting (eurogenic) effects. Albeit just because it is true for one serotonergic psychedelic doesn't necessarily mean it is true for all serotonergic psychedelics. Especially since LSD affects a wide range of serotonin and other receptor subtypes.

Comment: You have some great questions that I wish I knew the answers to.  Just a suggestion, you might want to see if your library can get [Goodman and Gilman's](http://www.amazon.com/Goodman-Gilmans-Pharmacological-Therapeutics-Twelfth/dp/0071624422/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1359610680&sr=1-3&keywords=goodman+gilman%27s+the+pharmacological+basis+of+therapeutics) for you.  I don't know if the answer to this would be in there, but it is definitely the "go-to" reference book for pharmacology.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll like [this article](http://www.unc.edu/~dlinz/Papers/The%20effects%20of%20non-medically%20used%20psychoactive%20drugs%20on%20monoamine%20neurotransmission%20in%20rat%20brain.pdf). It's on monoamine release / reuptake inhibition for a host of different psychedelic and empathogenic drugs.

This wakefulness inducing effect you describe for LSD is widely reported for all common 5-HT2 mediated psychedelics.