# Inverse Agonist vs Neutral Antagonist

Tags: neuroscience, brain

Could somebody explain in simplest terms the difference between inverse agonist and neutral antagonist?

Which one is more well natural and less likely to cause pathways to rebound?

Does neutral mean less effect such that stepping from an inverse agonist to neutral is the best idea to avoid withdrawal?

Edit: I am trying to determine how quickly the pathways rebound when stopped during withdrawal.  I would assume this might vary between inverse agonist and neutral antagonist.  I am not asking about actual withdrawal symptoms.

Comment: Where did you find these terms?

Comment: To those that are reading there are similar questions on this site https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/6972/do-serotonergic-5-ht2a-mediated-psychedelics-elicit-stimulant-effects  https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/66394/do-enzyme-inhibitors-change-equilibrium?s=2|40.7686

Comment: I will assume you are referring to these terms as used in molecular biology and pharmacology then. Have you looked at the wikipedia pages [inverse agonist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_agonist) and [receptor antagonist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receptor_antagonist)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many receptors have a natural constitutive, or "baseline", amount of response that they generate, they're not just an on-off switch. At baseline, many receptors will generate a partial response, which means that certain things binding to them can either increase or decrease their response.

A neutral antagonist is one that causes no change in the signaling response of the thing that it's binding to. It simply stays the same. Note that this can still be important, because a neutral antagonist can *block* the binding of other agonists, ones that *would* have generated a change in response, even if the antagonist itself doesn't cause a response.

An inverse agonist is something that decreases the response of the receptor from its baseline all by itself. Often, this is caused by stabilizing the receptor in it's "off" state. If the receptor has some degree of constitutive activity, an inverse agonist will decrease its activity.

See this graph from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_agonist) wikipedia page for a good explanation:

[image: Comparison graph of different types of agonists]

Comment: @William Please stop using the term "brain shock" - if you mean "withdrawal" then use the term others use: withdrawal. Knowing whether a something is an inverse agonist or an antagonist is not sufficient information to predict the extent of withdrawal symptoms.

Comment: @Bryan to repeat my question which one is "more natural?"

Comment: @William That term doesn't have any meaning outside of pseudoscience unless you give it a particular definition.

Comment: @BryanKrause I am trying to understand the long term impact and withdrawal effects of inverse agonists and neutral antagonists.  I can ask another question if mine isn't clear.  You are correct my question is not strictly using scientific terminology because I have found little information understanding differentiating the 2's impact.  What in my question isn't clear?  How quickly do pathways rebound?

Comment: @William I thought I already made clear in my comment: *Knowing whether a something is an inverse agonist or an antagonist is not sufficient information to predict the extent of withdrawal symptoms.*

Comment: @BryanKrause Are pathways ability to rebound not independent of their use case?  When I am implying rebound I am implying the restoration of the pathways not the actual withdrawal symptoms.

Comment: @William Binding affinity is probably closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: What is the horizontal drug column mean?

Comment: Why are antagonist listed if they don't do anything?

Comment: @William the horizontal axis is drug concentration. This is a particular type of receptor, that does something whether or not a drug or endogenous (thing the body produces) compound is bound to the receptor. Like the answer says, antagonists definitely *do* something. They compete with other compounds at the binding site. The change in activity of the receptor is only seen when you have two  compounds present. This is not shown in the figure.

Comment: @William think about what would happen if you had a neutral antagonist bound to a receptor and you added a full agonist. How would this be different from just adding a full agonist with no antagonist?  Then think about what would happen if you had a neutral antagonist bound to a receptor and you added an inverse agonist. How would this be different from just adding an inverse agonist?