# Compare affinity to potency h1 receptor

Tags: molecular-biology, pharmacology

This quote from [Miller (2004)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC487011/) makes it clear that the affinity of drugs for the H1 receptor does not correlate to sedation:

> Although both dosage and affinity for histamine H1 receptors play a part in the sedative effect of a medication, what ultimately determines sedative effect is the amount of the drug reaching the histamine H1 receptors in the central nervous system. For example, quetiapine, which has little affinity for the histamine H1 receptors, is a less potent antipsychotic medication and requires many more milligrams to be effective than do higher-potency medications such as risperidone and ziprasidone. Because of this, quetiapine has a greater sedative effect on patients in clinical use than do risperidone and ziprasidone.

[image]

Is there a mathematical way to compare affinity to potency between different drugs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few important things to consider as you interpret these data.

#### Here potency means Chlorpromazine equivalents

When your linked review refers to *potency*, it is likely referring to the old concept of chlorpromazine equivalents. The table in the article cites Jibson and Tandon in a review in CNS news special report from 2001. This is not a standard peer reviewed article, and I can't access it, but it lists relative potency in mg, with chlorpromazine set at 100mg and haloperidol at 2mg:

[image]

This is almost certainly chlorpromazine equivalents. You can read a discussion of the limitations of this understanding of antipsychotic potency [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3696254/), but these numbers are not based on a mathematically rigorous pharmacodynamic analysis. They are not consistent, especially for atypical antipsychotics, and are estimated based on [clinical data of the minimum effective dose](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12823080/) among other methods.

So, where the affinity in this article, $\frac{1}{K_D}$, has a rigorous pharmacodynamic definition, potency does not. Here it is, effectively, shorthand for how much of a drug you have to administer in order to get a therapeutic effect.

#### Antipsychotic drugs act at many CNS receptors

To understand exactly what Miller means when he says:

> For example, quetiapine, which has little affinity for the histamine H1 receptors, is a less potent antipsychotic medication and requires many more milligrams to be effective than do higher-potency medications such as risperidone and ziprasidone.

You need to understand that $H_1$ receptors do *not* mediate the primary clinical target. So the lower potency of quetiapine means you have to give *more* of it to have a clinical effect. Because of the higher typical dose of quetiapine, even though the affinity for $H_1$ receptors is relatively low, you're going to get more binding to $H_1$ than with, e.g., risperidone, which requires a lower dose.

Take a look at the chart in the [Richelson and Souder article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11132243) Miller cites to see the different receptor targets for these antipsychotic drugs.
[image]

The primary therapeutic targets (used to characterize the general clinical potency) are (probably) the $D_2$, $5HT_{1A}$, and $5HT_{2A}$ receptors. The action at the $H_1$ receptor is primarily an adverse effect. Miller is trying to say that the sedation effect *does* depend on affinity at $H_1$, but you also have to consider the dose required to get an effect at $D_2$ and the relevant $5HT$ receptors.

#### A rigorous definition of potency involves simplification

There *is* a rigorous definition of potency for an agonist (and also of inhibition for an antagonist, and antipsychotic drugs are antagonists). Potency is both distinct from and dependent on affinity.  I'd recommend [Goodman and Gillman Chapter 3](https://accesspharmacy.mhmedical.com/content.aspx?bookid=2189&sectionid=170349571), if you'd like to learn more. It's not particularly relevant to understanding this article, in part because Miller doesn't use this definition of potency, and in part because the model involves a single ligand-receptor interaction that directly mediates a desired effect. It's based on the following equation, where $LR^*$ is an activated ligand-receptor: $L + R \rightleftharpoons LR \rightleftharpoons LR^*$.  Because both desired and adverse effects of antipsychotics involve actions at many different receptors [even beyond those in Richelson and Souder](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1571994/), the simple model falls short.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I just saw your comment.  I need to get a hold of the book to try to understand more before I assume you explanation isn't adequate.

Comment: @William what do you need help understanding?

Comment: @William the basic idea here is that the article is talking about a general clinical concept of potency, and the clinical (side) effect of sedation for drugs that are given in very different doses. This is not a single receptor system, and Miller is not talking about the relationship between affinity for $H_1$ and potency at $H_1$. I've studied this a good deal, in and beyond medical school. I'm happy to help answer your questions about it if you need more help. Just ask.

Comment: I'm trying to compare the drugs and from what I have gathered from reading your post is that there is no way to rank their sedation except with clinical trials and comparing sedation described by the patient.

Comment: I am asking for an equation I don't see where potency is plugged into the equation. Can you please post a Mathematical example walking though either Zyprexa or Seroquel.

Comment: Hi @William. If your goal is to understand this article, there is no equation that is going to relate chlorpromazine equivalents (potency in this article) to affinity, $\frac{1}{K_D}$ at the $H_1$ receptor. They are different things all together, with no known mathematical model connecting them. If your goal is to understand potency, olanzapine and quetiapine are not very good places to start. They are inhibitors at  many different receptors. I'm not sure what you would want in a mathematical example walking through either of them. Were you able to get a copy of Goodman and Gillman?

Comment: Okay ignore my last question.  According to Wikipedia the h1 receptor of seroquel is a neutral antagonist which means it does nothing on the receptors which seems to be at odds with miller?

Comment: @William all of these antipsychotics are antagonist, as I've said, and this is not at odds with miller at all. Affinity has to do with the strength of binding, not with the downstream effect. It seems like someone may have taught you something different along the way.

Comment: I guess I assumed h1 antagonist mean neutral antagonist and this answer states neutral antongists bind but don't alter the response https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/73706/inverse-agonist-vs-neutral-antagonist

Comment: @William Affinity describes binding, not the effect of binding. Anything that binds will have a dissociation constant, no matter how binding effects the receptor, and the inverse of that dissociation constant is the affinity. Also, neutral antagonists *do* have an effect on the receptor. They prevent binding and activation by an agonist.

Comment: "In each of these studies, the atypical antipsychotic (risperidone, olanzapine, quetiapine, and ziprasidone) caused less sedation than did the conventional antipsychotic used for comparison, haloperidol, except in the highest doses. " This seems contrary to evidence in the article"